# Android SDK File path and JAVA path not be set but we already give the right path

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Severity    Code    Description Project Project Rank    File    Line    Column  Suppression State
Warning     An unexpected error occurred trying to initialize Android Designer. Please verify the Android SDK path and the  Java Development Kit path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu. Please see the logs for more details.      1       0   0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check you set your java path to a JDK not a JRE.

Ensure that your Android SDK path is correct as well.